# How to Crawl .pdf links using Apache Nutch

Tags: apache, hadoop, nutch

I got a website to crawl which includes some links to pdf files.
I want nutch to crawl that link and dump them as .pdf files.
I am using Apache Nutch1.6 also i am tring this in java as

```
ToolRunner.run(NutchConfiguration.create(), new Crawl(),
                                 tokenize(crawlArg));
 SegmentReader.main(tokenize(dumpArg));
```

can some one help me on this

Answer (score 3):

If you want Nutch to crawl and index your pdf documents, you have to enable document crawling and the Tika plugin:

1. Document crawling

   1.1 Edit regex-urlfilter.txt and remove any occurence of "pdf"

   ```
   # skip image and other suffixes we can't yet parse
   # for a more extensive coverage use the urlfilter-suffix plugin
   -\.(gif|GIF|jpg|JPG|png|PNG|ico|ICO|css|CSS|sit|SIT|eps|EPS|wmf|WMF|zip|ZIP|ppt|PPT|mpg|MPG|xls|XLS|gz|GZ|rpm|RPM|tgz|TGZ|mov|MOV|exe|EXE|jpeg|JPEG|bmp|BMP|js|JS)$
   ```

   1.2 Edit suffix-urlfilter.txt and remove any occurence of "pdf"

   1.3 Edit nutch-site.xml, add "parse-tika" and "parse-html" in the plugin.includes section

   ```
   <property>
     <name>plugin.includes</name>
     <value>protocol-http|urlfilter-regex|parse-(html|tika|text)|index-(basic|anchor)|scoring-opic|urlnormalizer-(pass|regex|basic)</value>
     <description>Regular expression naming plugin directory names to
     include.  Any plugin not matching this expression is excluded.
     In any case you need at least include the nutch-extensionpoints plugin. By
     default Nutch includes crawling just HTML and plain text via HTTP,
     and basic indexing and search plugins. In order to use HTTPS please enable 
     protocol-httpclient, but be aware of possible intermittent problems with the 
     underlying commons-httpclient library.
     </description>
   </property>
   ```
2. If what you really want is to download all pdf files from a page, you can use something like [Teleport in Windows](http://www.tenmax.com/teleport/pro/home.htm) or Wget in *nix.

Answer (score -1):

you can either write your own own plugin, for pdf mimetype 
 or there is embedded apache-tika parser, that can retrieve text from pdf..