# Crawl PDF documents using nutch

Tags: pdf, nutch

I have to crawl PDF documents too from given URL...
suggest any tool/API to crawl PDF docs also...
now I am using nutch to crawl but I couldn't crawl PDF from given URL...should I use any plugin to crawl PDF in nutch?

seed.txt --> http://nutch.apache.org
regex-urlfilter.txt--->+^http://([a-z0-9]*.)*nutch.apache.org/

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Check out http://amac4.blogspot.com/2013/07/configuring-nutch-to-crawl-urls.html

Answer (score 2):

1. Edit **regex-urlfilter.txt** and remove any occurence of "pdf"
2. Edit **suffix-urlfilter.txt** and remove any occurence of "pdf"
3. Edit **nutch-site.xml**, add "parse-tika" and "parse-html" in the
   plugin.includes section. this should look like this

this answer came from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17442052/how-to-crawl-pdf-links-using-apache-nutch) . I have tested it  when working on Nutch

```
<property>


<name>plugin.includes</name>
  <value>protocol-http|urlfilter-regex|parse-(html|tika|text)|index-(basic|anchor)|scoring-opic|urlnormalizer-(pass|regex|basic)</value>
  <description>
    ...
  </description>
</property>
```

Comment: After doing this what will it return a pdf file or just pdf file text?

Comment: Nutch will contain both the raw file and the parsed text from the file (if parsed). Using the `bin/nutch readseg` and `bin/nutch dump` commands you can get access to both (https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/CommandLineOptions).

Answer (score 1):

I found that even you used the tika plugin, it still can't crawl the pdf or any ms office file into the crawldb. you need to **add the url** that you want to crawl **in the** **white-list in nutch-site.xml** in order to get the pdf and any ms office file:

```
<property>
  <name>http.robot.rules.whitelist</name>
  <value>xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx</value>
  <description>Comma separated list of hostnames or IP addresses to ignore 
  robot rules parsing for. Use with care and only if you are explicitly
  allowed by the site owner to ignore the site's robots.txt!
  </description>
</property>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Nutch's [parse-tika](http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/TikaPlugin) plugin. Plain text, XML, OpenDocument (OpenOffice.org), Microsoft Office (Word, Excel, Powerpoint), PDF, RTF, MP3 (ID3 tags) are all parsed by the Tika plugin